# RunProcess vs. Run - cpu usage

Tags: performance-tuning, bugs, timing

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and persisting through 11.2**

 `RunProcess` is new in 10.0

---

Comparing the cpu usage of

```
RunProcess[{"sleep", "10"}]
```

and

```
Run["sleep 10"]
```

The mathematica kernel spikes up to 100% cpu usage in the case of `RunProcess` during the time of "external calculation", while it stays calm with `Run`.

Why is that? And how do I avoid this behaviour?

Mathematica version: 11.1.1

Comment: I can confirm this. redhat/mma11.1.  `RunProcess` connects to the process *stdout* , while `Run` does not. I don't see why that should take so much cpu though.

Comment: Confirmed on OS X too.

Comment: Did you report this to Wolfram Support?  If you haven't, please do so, and let us know what they said. It smells like a bug to me.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Yes I did. The report was forwarded to their developers. I'll post an answer when the issue is resolved.

Comment: Confirmed on Windows 10, mma 11.1; CentOS, mma 11.2.

Answer (score 6):

more of curiosity than anything else I tried this:

```
p = StartProcess[{"sleep", "10"}]
While[ProcessStatus[p, "Running"]]
ProcessStatus[p]
ReadString[p, EndOfBuffer]
ProcessInformation[p]
```

you get essentially the same result with no noticeable CPU hit. (the kernel does not show up on the linux `top` list)