# Feeding Executable Arguments into Run - or using RunProcess without the kernel CPU usage

Tags: performance-tuning, bugs, external-calls, automation

I am trying to automate the submission of many executables with variable parameter values via *Mathematica* on Windows 10 x64.

Running the executable from *Mathematica* works great for executables that take **no arguments** via the following:

`Run["myExecutable.exe"]`

If - however - you wish to feed in parameter values, the following is the closest I get to the desired behavior (where the "900..." are my arguments to be passed to the EXE):

`RunProcess["myExecutable.exe","ExitCode","900 0.01 2 30 30"]`

However, on my machine this requires 15% CPU usage by the executable (as expected) ***&*** **another 15% CPU usage from the *Mathematica* kernel itself, unlike the `Run[~]` above.**  This is because `RunProcess[~]` returns something to the *Mathematica* kernel, whereas `Run[~]` does not; this bug is reported [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/157508/runprocess-vs-run-cpu-usage).  This halves the efficiency of scripting and makes it unfeasible!

To avoid this bug in `RunProcess[~]`, I am wondering if there is either:

> 1)  a likely undocumented way to make `RunProcess[~]` not return
>   anything, thus preventing the kernel from chunking away @ 15% CPU
>   usage waiting on an exit code (or other info),
>
> 2)  a way to feed in arguments via `Run[~]` instead?

For (1), I've no idea; according to docs & returned errors, there's no "None" option available for arg2.

For (2), there are guides on how to make `Run[~]` feed in arguments [here](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2006/May/msg00457.html) from a WRI employee and elsewhere on the Stack Exchange site, e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64931/how-to-call-external-commands-with-parameters-on-win7).

(2) boils down to my not understanding what the Windows Command Prompt needs to see in order to feed in those parameters.  This is addressed in part in the first of the above two links, but I cannot for the life of me figure it out.  However, I would think `RunProcess[~]` must know, because it works, it just hogs 2x the necessary CPU usage!  But I do not know what it "says" to the command prompt in order to run the executable and feed in the arguments!   Another resource regarding this topic is [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64931/how-to-call-external-commands-with-parameters-on-win7)

Does anyone know how properly feed in arguments to `Run[~]` on Windows, or `StartProcess[~]` even given the work-around [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/157508/runprocess-vs-run-cpu-usage) sounds as if it works on Linux?  (See below.)

While I don't have a minimal working example with a personally compiled exectuable, the behavior can be observed using this (again from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/157508/runprocess-vs-run-cpu-usage)):

`RunProcess[{"sleep","10"}]`

vs.

`Run["sleep 10"]`

Unlike for the Linux instantiation I believe users in that referenced question are using, `Run["sleep 10"]` does not pass the argument appropriately on Windows, (i.e. `Run["myExecutable.exe 900 0.01 2 30 30"]` does not work on Windows as an equivalent to the resource-hogging yet functional `RunProcess["myExecutable.exe",...]` above)! :-(

The seemingly Linux-friendly work-around (again [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/157508/runprocess-vs-run-cpu-usage)) using `StartProcess[{"myExecutable.exe", "900 0.01 2 30 30"}]` successfully runs the exectuable, but it waits indefinitely come time to feed in arguments, implying there is an issue feeding in arguments (despite the format being the same as what works with `RunProcess[~]`.  I have tried segregating arguments using `StartProcess[{"myExecutable.exe", "900", "0.01", "2", "30", "30"}]` to no avail.

Comment: Did you try the "workaround" (using `StartProcess`) proposed in the thread concerning the bug with `RunProcess` ?

Comment: Hi @SquareOne, thank you.  Yes I tried that.  It does run the executable, but the executable hangs when it comes time to feed in the arguments.  That is, unless I insert a `RunProcess[~]` as above, but that then reproduces the above highlighted bug.  Hanging when it comes time to feed in arguments with my executable (and seemingly not actually sleeping for 10s with `RunProcess[{"sleep", "10"}]` is called) seem to boil down to not properly feeding in arguments with `Run[~]` and `StartProcess[~]` on Windows, however it works for `RunProcess[~]` in the same environment, just with 100% overhead.

Comment: As the `RunProcess` way seems  clearly buggy for now, you should focus on `Run`. There are probably examples on this site where `Run` works successfully with windows for commands with arguments ? Report here if they work for you also. But it's weird that, if I understand well, even the simple `Run["sleep 10"]` does not work for you with windows OS? Try maybe to follow the strategy described in [this post](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2006/May/msg00457.html) you cited  earlier, using `cmd.exe` command on windows prompt and then from mma with `Run`. (I can't help, i have OSX).

Comment: Thanks, @SquareOne.  I haven't a solution on the Mathematica end, but the difference between how `Run[~]` & `RunProcess[~]` feed in arguments is such that `RunProcess[~]` circumvents the expectation that *when using `Run`* - with a C++ written EXE feeding in parameters using the console input "cin" command - the parameters must be fed in AFTER the command calling the EXE is entered; parameters can't be entered as in "sleep 10" if the "sleep.exe" was compiled with the input using "cin".  However, using `RunProcess` arguments work; perhaps internally it enters arguments AFTER calling the EXE.

Comment: I will leave the question open as others may come across the bug or infer from the question a better resolution than changing the EXE source code; I am still not convinced `Run["sleep 10"]` behaves properly on Windows.  On the off-chance someone is having this issue with a C++ EXE they wrote, if you use the Boost library to use flags to indicate parameters, it will work in a single line such as "sleep -t 10", which may then be used with `Run[~]`.